# XDocument System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap, xmldocument

I am trying to read the XML in the soapmessage. the XML is 23822 lines.
An exception with `System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.'` occur.

Below is the code to read the XML response:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(soapmessage);

            var ids = xdoc.Element("FourMonthsAhead1Result")
                 .Elements("PlantForecastIntervals")
                 .Elements("<PlantForecastIntervalNode>")
                 .Select(item => item.Element("IntervalStartTime").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(ids);
```

Below is a small snippet of the response of the XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <s:Body>
        <FourMonthsAhead1Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <FourMonthsAhead1Result xmlns="LSS.solar.webservice">
                <PlantDescription xmlns="http://base.datacontract">*PlantName*</PlantDescription>
                <PlantForecastIntervalsCount xmlns="http://base.datacontract">2976</PlantForecastIntervalsCount>
                <ForecastStartDate xmlns="http://base.datacontract">2021-10-08T13:35:55.912612</ForecastStartDate>
                <ForecastEndDate xmlns="http://base.datacontract">2021-10-08T13:35:55.9126123</ForecastEndDate>
                <PlantForecastIntervals xmlns="http://base.datacontract">
                    <PlantForecastIntervalNode>
                        <IntervalStartTime>2021-10-01T00:00:00</IntervalStartTime>
                        <IntervalEndTime>2021-10-01T00:15:00</IntervalEndTime>
                        <IntervalLength>15</IntervalLength>
                        <ForecastResultParameter>FourMonthsAhead1</ForecastResultParameter>
                        <ForecastValue>0</ForecastValue>
                        <ValueUnit>MW</ValueUnit>
                    </PlantForecastIntervalNode>
                    <PlantForecastIntervalNode>
                        <IntervalStartTime>2021-10-01T00:15:00</IntervalStartTime>
                        <IntervalEndTime>2021-10-01T00:30:00</IntervalEndTime>
                        <IntervalLength>15</IntervalLength>
                        <ForecastResultParameter>FourMonthsAhead1</ForecastResultParameter>
                        <ForecastValue>0</ForecastValue>
                        <ValueUnit>MW</ValueUnit>
                    </PlantForecastIntervalNode>
                </PlantForecastIntervals>
            </FourMonthsAhead1Result>
        </FourMonthsAhead1Response>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `XDocument.Parse` to create `XDocument` from a content string instead of `XDocument.Load`, which used to create `XDocument` from file by specifying its path or uri:

```
XDocument xDoc;

string soap = File.ReadAllText("H:\\soap.xml");

// Parse used to get data from a string
xDoc = XDocument.Parse(soap);

// Load can be used to get data from specified file
xDoc = XDocument.Load("H:\\soap.xml");

// Load attempt from string content will throw you an error
xDoc = XDocument.Load(soap);
```